# Jquery addClass function not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I have a problem with jQuery addClass() that is not working in firefox, meaning that the class is not added to current element. And the following is working in Chrome and Safari (not tested on IE).

Here is the CSS :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".placeholder").click(function(){
     $(this).addClass("placeholder-small");
     $(this).prev("input").focus();
    });
    $("input").on("focus",function(){
     $(this).nextAll(".placeholder").first().addClass("placeholder-small");
    });
   });
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;outline:none;-webkit-appearance:none}
   html, body {padding:0;margin:0;background-color:#131419;color:#fff;font-family:"DIN", arial;font-size:14px;letter-spacing:0.15em;font-weight:300}
   input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type=number], input[type="password"] {max-width:250px;width:100%;background-color:transparent;border-radius:0;border:0;border-bottom:1px solid #b6b6b8;color:#fff;font-family:"DIN",arial;font-size:inherit;padding:10px 8px;margin:10px 0;z-index:1}
   .required {position:relative}
   .required:after {position:absolute;top:0;right:0;content:"*";color:#ff0000;z-index:9}
   .placeholder {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;transition:all .2s;z-index:0}
   textarea ~ .placeholder {top:-135px}
   .placeholder-small, input:-webkit-autofill ~ .placeholder {transform:translateY(-125%);-moz-transform: translateY(-125%);font-size:0.85em;color:#616777}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div style="padding:50px"><span class="required"><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" pattern=".{1,}" required minlength="1" maxlength="255" /><div class="placeholder">Prénom</div></span></div>
  </form>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".placeholder").click(function(){
     $(this).addClass("placeholder-small");
     $(this).prev("input").focus();
    });
    $("input").on("focus",function(){
     $(this).nextAll(".placeholder").first().addClass("placeholder-small");
    });
   });
  </script>
```

If needed, you can see it live on this page :
https://www.goldenkeyz.com/fr/signup/

Comment: Please add your HTML and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Barmar, post edited, thank you

Comment: Could you show the actual HTML in the question, not the PHP that generates it, so that the snippet will execute properly?

Comment: Very weird. The Debugger tab says that `this` is `div.placeholder.placeholder-small`, but the added class doesn't show up in the Elements tab, and the CSS for the class isn't being applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
.placeholder-small, input:-webkit-autofill ~ .placeholder { ...
```

The webkit specific declaration is causing parsing to fail on Firefox, as it is supposed to. If the parser encounters something it doesn't recognize, it will disregard the whole code block:

> The selector consists of everything up to (but not including) the
>   first left curly brace ({). A selector always goes together with a
>   {}-block. When a user agent can't parse the selector (i.e., it is not
>   valid CSS3), it must ignore the {}-block as well.

If you remove the webkit part, or separate it to it's own statement, the code works as expected:

```
.placeholder-small {
    transform: translateY(-125%);
    font-size: 0.85em;
    color: #616777;
}

input:-webkit-autofill ~ .placeholder {
    transform: translateY(-125%);
    font-size: 0.85em;
    color: #616777;
}
```

Note that you don't need to use `-moz-transform`, the plain transform has been enough since version 16 from 2012.